# Wordpress display private and public posts on Blog Page

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there away in Wordpress to display both my private and public posts on the blog page.

I am also looking for a way on the single post page if it is private displaying a message indicating it is.

So is there away to display both private and public posts on my blog page and is there a if condition for if private post?

Comment: Try this - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/78333/how-do-i-check-if-a-post-is-private
It seems it can solve your issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can add this into query let say wp_query where you use for getting all post, in template or function anywhere.

just you can put below query into your template.

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'blog',
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'private')
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

just put this into your template and you cat get all your private and publish post into template.

Comment: Please check my edited answer just put this into your template.

Answer (score 1):

You can get your 'private' and 'public' posts in this way

```
$args = array(
    'post_status' => array( 'publish', 'private')
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

And then you can use `get_post_status()` inside the loop to get the status and indicate the message.

For your reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_status/